# my website has flash needed to change to a static image when website is viewed on mobile when using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, flash, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Hi all I am using bootstrap for the first time. I am using Bootstrap 3.

I have created an a front page and was trying to figure out when a user is on the website on a desktop machine the Flash or the swf can be seen. But of course when on mobile for example Apple products they can't view the flash or swf file.

Is there a way so when a user uses their mobile or tablet a static image or carousel comes into play just something similar to the menu buttons collapsing to the 3 lines in tablet and mobile?

The Flash page for test:
http://inbreathe.co.uk/bootstrap0/flash.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232801/alternative-image-when-flash-banner-is-not-available-using-html-css

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can hide the container containing flash for mobile and show another container with a static image.

Something like:

```
<div class="visible-xs visible-sm">
  ... put your static image here ...
</div>
<div class="visible-md visible-lg">
  ... put your flash here ...
</div>
```

Check [the responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for more informations.

Comment: Great thanks it works, much appreciated. I just had to replace the bootstrap.css with the bootstrap.min.css as that worked. As the bootstrap.min.css maybe messy, but has all the css compared to the bootstrap.css.